# Why doesn't the Function see state updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my Component :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles/editIntern.sass";

const EditIntern = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [name, inputName] = useState("");
  const [email, inputEmail] = useState("");
  const [start, inputStart] = useState("");
  const [end, inputEnd] = useState("");

  const [errorNameEmpty, isErrorNameEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorEmailValid, isErrorEmailValid] = useState(false);
  const [errorStartEmpty, isErrorStartEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorEndEmpty, isErrorEndEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorDate, isErrorDate] = useState(false);
  const [sendData, setSendData] = useState(false);

  const validEmail = new RegExp(/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/);

  const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let startDate = new Date(start).getTime();
    let endDate = new Date(end).getTime();

    isErrorDate(startDate > endDate || startDate === endDate);
    isErrorNameEmpty(name.trim() === "");
    isErrorEmailValid(email.trim() === "" || !validEmail.test(email));
    isErrorStartEmpty(start.trim() === "");
    isErrorEndEmpty(end.trim() === "");

    if (
      errorNameEmpty ||
      errorEmailValid ||
      errorStartEmpty ||
      errorEndEmpty ||
      errorDate
    ) {
      setSendData(false);
      console.log("Net");
    } else {
      setSendData(true);
      console.log("Da");
    }

    let newIntern = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      internshipStart: start + "T00:00+00Z",
      internshipEnd: end + "T00:00+00Z",
    };

    if (sendData) {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(newIntern),
      };
      fetch(`http://localhost:3001/interns/${id}`, requestOptions).then(
        (response) => response.json()
      );
      console.log("Good");
    } else {
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIntern = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/interns/${id}`);
      const intern = await response.json();
      console.log(intern);
      inputName(intern.name);
      inputEmail(intern.email);
      inputStart(intern.internshipStart.slice(0, 10));
      inputEnd(intern.internshipEnd.slice(0, 10));
    };
    fetchIntern();
    console.log(`I want to get intern with id: ${id}!`);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <img className="Logo" src="../assets/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
      <section className="EditIntern">
        <NavLink to="/">
          <button className="EditIntern_back">
            <img
              className="EditIntern_back-img"
              src="../assets/button_back_icon.svg"
              alt="button_back"
            />{" "}
            Back to list
          </button>
        </NavLink>
        <form className="EditIntern_form">
          <h4 className="EditIntern_form-title">Edit</h4>
          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_name">
            Full name *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorNameEmpty
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_name  EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_name"
            }
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorNameEmpty ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_name--icon"
                src="../assets/error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_name">
                Name can't be empty
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_email">
            Email address *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorEmailValid
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_email EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_email"
            }
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputEmail(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorEmailValid ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_email--icon"
                src="../assets/error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_email">
                Example: email@gmail.com
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_start">
            Internship start *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorStartEmpty
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_start EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_start"
            }
            type="date"
            name="email"
            value={start}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputStart(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorStartEmpty ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_start--icon"
                src="../assets/error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_start">
                Start date can't be empty
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_end">
            Internship end *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorEndEmpty
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_end EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_end"
            }
            type="date"
            name="email"
            value={end}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputEnd(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorEndEmpty ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_end--icon"
                src="../assets/error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_end">
                End date can't be empty
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
          {errorDate ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_start--icon"
                src="../assets/error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_end--icon"
                src="../assets/error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_date">
                Start date more or equal to end date
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <input
            className="EditIntern_form-submit"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            onClick={onFormSubmit}
          />
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditIntern;
```

I have onFormSubmit function which should send a request only if there were no errors while filling out the form ( All states with an error state should be false). However, now when you first click on Submit, the function works correctly, but in any case, sets sendData to true. In other words, the function does not see changes in the state of the errors.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from the fact that setting state in react is an asynchronous operation,

you can remove the `sendData` and make request directly

```
 if (
      errorNameEmpty ||
      errorEmailValid ||
      errorStartEmpty ||
      errorEndEmpty ||
      errorDate
    ) {
      // show error message or ... 
    } else {

      // make  the data object
      let newIntern = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      internshipStart: start + "T00:00+00Z",
      internshipEnd: end + "T00:00+00Z",
    };

      // make the request
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(newIntern),
      };
      fetch(`http://localhost:3001/interns/${id}`, 
       requestOptions).then(
        (response) => response.json()
      );
      console.log("Good");
      console.log("Da");
  }
```

see this for more details
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-setstate-method-async/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed sendData as you said. After reading the article that you attached, I realized that now onFormSubmit does not see state changes due to the nature of state. As far as I understand, the output can be async / await, but I don’t quite understand where to use it.